# Retrying after Database deadlock encountered hit on attempt 1 at query : INSERT INTO civicrm_mailing_recipients?

Tags: database, mysql, authorize.net, deadlocks

Drupal 10.2.3 ,  CiviCRM 5.70.0, PHP 8.2.13, MySQL: 10.6.16-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, nginx/1.18.0

Got the below in logs after almost each contribution (contributions status="Completed" ) :

> [debug] Could not find an entry for x_subscription_id
> [info] Contribution 12345 updated successfully
> [info] Contribution 12345 Receipt sent

and

> [info] Retrying after Database deadlock encountered hit on attempt 1 at query : INSERT INTO civicrm_mailing_recipients (mailing_id, contact_id, email_id)
> SELECT 269, i.contact_id, i.email_id
> FROM civicrm_contact contact_a
> INNER JOIN civicrm_tmp_e_inrecipient_2d90d485a4c12b028bd5ce7fd27ee064 i ON contact_a.id = i.contact_id
> INNER JOIN civicrm_email e ON e.id = i.email_id
> WHERE (( 1 ))
> GROUP BY e.email
> ORDER BY MIN(i.contact_id), MIN(i.email_id)

There are mentions of thr  **x_subscription_id** is  [from 2017 and related to Authorize.net payment processor.](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/search?q=x_subscription_id)  so this might be somehow related to receipts processing but it is not quite clear for me if maybe we should check the database configuration & performance bottlenecks first. Please advice.

Comment: Do you have any extension that creates mailing upon the submission?

Comment: None to my knowledge, got rid of Rules etc., and all mailings are being managed manually. Smart group(-s) perhaps?